# Highcharts not plotting while reading from CSV file

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying highcharts pie-charts. It works when providing the data within the code itself But when I tried for external csv file, it is not plotting. I have a csv file which is containing entries like this:

```
a,10
b,20
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Highcharts Example</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                    var d = [];

                    var options = {
                            chart: {
                                    renderTo: 'container',
                                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                                    plotShadow: false
                            },
                            title: {
                                    text: 'Test Graph'
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                    pie: {
                                            cursor: 'pointer',
                                            allowPointSelect: true,
                                            dataLabels: {
                                                    enabled: true,
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                                                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                    type: 'pie',
                                    name: 'Test',
                                    data: d
                            }]
                    };

                    $.get('test.csv',function(data) {
                            var rows = data.split('\n');
                            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
                                    var arr = rows[i].split(',');
                                    d.push([arr[0],parseFloat(arr[1])]);
                            }

                            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                    });
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
          <script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

          <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
```

On changing the line:

```
 var rows = data.split('\n');
```

to

```
 var rows = "a,10\nb,20".split('\n');
```

It works.

Comment: As to your `Highcharts.Chart(options)` call, you're setting `options.series.data = d` *before* you make the call to your `csv`. `d` is not a reference where you can modify it later and have it modify all of it's references; you need to set `options.series.data = d;` before you call the chart initializer where you pass it `options`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Can you please tell me by editing the code.. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: Put `options.series.data = d;` between the *end* of your `for` loop and the call to `Highcharts.Chart(options);`

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I added `options.series.data = d;` between the end of for loop and call to `Highcharts.Chart(options)` still it didn't work.

Comment: You probably have issues with what or how you're accessing what you get back. Use `console.log(data);` to debug the response. (If you've not used `console`, you have to have one open first.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thank you very much. I will learn how to use console.log.

Comment: In order to help you to solve this problem, please attach here, what exactly are you storing in d array, and how it looks like?